# Most efficient way to consume messages from queue

Tags: scala, rabbitmq

I've some queues on RabbitMQ and i'm using a **while(true)** looping and my processor is running near 100% all the time.

```
def processQueue(queueName:String) = Future {
    val connection = buildConnection()
    val channel = connection.createChannel()
    try {
        channel.queueDeclare(queueName,true, false, false, null)
        channel.basicQos(100)
        val consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel)
        channel.basicConsume(queueName, false, consumer)
        while(true){
            val delivery = consumer.nextDelivery()
            val message = new String(delivery.getBody)               
            doSomething(message)
            channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope.getDeliveryTag, false)
        }
    } catch {
        case e:Exception => Logger.error("Error processing messages. ", e)
    } finally {
        channel.close()
        connection.close()
    }
}
```

What is best approach and/or most efficient way to consume messages from queue? I implemented it to be a synchronous process.

Comment: which rabbitmq library are you using?

Comment: amqp-client 3.5.4 (official client)